# Is it possible to inject a view scoped bean into a @FacesValidator in JSF?

Tags: jsf, validation, jsf-2.2

As the title implies, I'm trying to inject a view scoped bean into a validator decorated by `@FacesValidator` as follows.

```
@FacesValidator(value = "priceRangeValidator")
public final class PriceRangeValidator implements Validator {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{rangeSliderBean}")
    private RangeSliderBean rangeSliderBean; //Setter only.

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        // The bean instance is unavailable here. It is null.
    }
}
```

The target view scoped bean - `RangeSliderBean` is unavailable in the `validate()` method.

---

I'm temporarily following the following way to get an instance of that bean in the `validate()` method itself.

```
RangeSliderBean rangeSliderBean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{rangeSliderBean}", RangeSliderBean.class);
```

Is it possible to inject a view scoped JSF managed bean into a validator using the `@ManagedProperty` annotation or something else?

<sub>I'm using JSF 2.2.6.</sub>

---

**UPDATE:**

This does not work on [Mojarra 2.3.0-m01](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.3.0-m01/). The bean instance still remains `null` as it did before. This time long after this post, I took a corresponding view scoped CDI bean (`@ManagedProperty` was replaced by `@Inject`).

Answer (score 0):

Try dynamic Injection by evaluating an expression using [Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html) like this.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
RangeSliderBean rangeSliderBean = facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{rangeSliderBean}", RangeSliderBean .class);
```

Comment: In JSF 2.2, annotations like `@ManagedProperty`, `@EJB` should work for `@FacesValidator` or `@FacesConverter`. Likewise in this case, it does not work even when I decorate the validator by `@ManagedBean` with a desired/required scope.

Comment: Tiny, that JSF 2.2 statement is not true. This is explained in among others http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesValidator